# How to click on radio button based column value?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, radio-button

I have a table as mentioned below:`(select, Advisor, Advisor Name and Relationship are coulmn names)`. I could not paste it as a table because of the restrictions.

Select:

```
RadioButton1                    
Radiobutton2
```

Advisor:

```
Advisor1
Advisor2
```

AdvisorName:

```
Name1
Name2
```

Relationship:

```
Secondary
Primary
```

`radiobuttons` does not have label names.

My scenario is: I need to click on the radio button where `Relationship=Primary`. Can you please suggest how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Given the following [HTML table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) structure

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Select</th>
        <th>Advisor</th>
        <th>Advisor Name</th>
        <th>Relationship</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>RadioButton1</div>
            <div>RadioButton2</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>Advisor1</div>
            <div>Advisor2</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>Name1</div>
            <div>Name2</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>Secondary</div>
            <div>Primary</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can match the `Primary` value for the `Relationship` column using the following expression:

```
//table/tr/td[count(//table/tr/th[.='Relationship']/preceding-sibling::th) + 1]/div[text()='Primary']
```

[image]

Where:

- `count(//table/tr/th[.='Relationship']/preceding-sibling::th) + 1` - returns the position (column number) of the `Relationship` column which is `4`
- the rest of the expression basically chooses [div](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp) having the `Primary` text from  4th column of the table

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

---

In the majority of cases it's easier to use [Table class](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements/blob/master/htmlelements-java/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/htmlelements/element/Table.java) from [HtmlElements](http://htmlelements.qatools.ru) framework